# Selecting from a Hash

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Codecademy and I'm having trouble with this [problem](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-Qn7Qw/2/4?curriculum_id=5059f8619189a5000201fbcb#):

> Create a new variable, good_movies, and set it equal to the result of
>   calling .select on movie_ratings, selecting only movies with a rating
>   strictly greater than 3.

Here's my code:

```
movie_ratings = {
  memento: 3,
  primer: 3.5,
  the_matrix: 5,
  truman_show: 4,
  red_dawn: 1.5,
  skyfall: 4,
  alex_cross: 2,
  uhf: 1,
  lion_king: 3.5
}
# Add your code below!
good_movies = movie_ratings.each {|k,v| v > 3}
```

Here is the result:

```
{:memento=>3, :primer=>3.5, :the_matrix=>5, :truman_show=>4, :red_dawn=>1.5, :skyfall=>4, :alex_cross=>2, :uhf=>1, :lion_king=>3.5}
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:

> Oops, try again. It looks like good_movies includes memento, but it
>   shouldn't.

"memento" has a value of 3 and I thought that my "v > 3" condition would filter it out; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's right there in the instructions: "Create a new variable, good_movies, and set it equal to the result of calling **.select** on movie_ratings, selecting only movies with a rating strictly greater than 3.". You used .each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Hash#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-select) to filter as per conditions, not [`Hash#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-each).

```
movie_ratings.select {|k,v| v > 3}
```

Basically `Hash#each` returns the receiver on which you called it, and in your case, it the original hash `movie_ratings`. Indeed it contains `memento` key, as I said, `Hash#each` not for *filtering* purposes. But `Hash#select`, will filter `memento` with its value out from the output `Hash`, thus your code will not give any objections.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, even then, why didn't my code exclude "memento"?

Comment: @Haque1, because you used `movie_ratings.each` instead of `movie_ratings.select`.

Comment: still, wouldn't the v > 3 condition filter out any values <= 3?

Comment: Not with `.each`. `{:a=>1,:b=>2}.each{|k,v| v == 2 } => {:a=>1, :b=>2}`

Comment: `{:a=>1,:b=>2}.select{|k,v| v == 2 } => {:b=>2}`

Answer (score 1):

You must have change `each` for `select` like this: `good_movies = movie_ratings.select {|k,v| v > 3}`